# asp.net mvc Deploying SB Admin 2 on local IIS issues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I downloaded SB Admin 2 asp.net mvc template application. I was able to bring it up with Visual Studio IIS fine

[image]

I added the web application to my local IIS and pointed to the folder but when I typed mysite.local on my browser, I get this

[image]

I am not sure how to add it my local iis. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the browser cannot find the path to the local resources. Can we see the code please?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some issues with the side navigation not collapsing (I was looking for a solution to this when I came across your post) but it should display properly if you use "~/" for your stylesheet and JQuery references. Below are the modifications I made to the header references:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="~/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="~/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="~/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also at the bottom of the page, these are the modifications I made to the JQuery references:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="~/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="~/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```